# Aggregate the couchbase document Data

Tags: couchbase

In couchbase, is there any aggregation method or template (Without N1QL) for aggregating the values?

My couchbase doc follows this format:

```
{"Students":[
    {
    "Student_id": "101",
    "Name": "Jon",
    "Course" : "Engineer"
    },
    {
    "Student_id": "102",
    "Name": "Snow",
    "Course" : "Medical"
    },
    {
    "Student_id": "103",
    "Name": "Walter",
    "Course" : "Chemistry"
    },
    {
    "Student_id": "104",
    "Name": "White",
    "Course" : "Chemistry"
    }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with N1QL as follows.

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES("f001",{"Students":[ { "Student_id": "101", "Name": "Jon", "Course" : "Engineer" }, { "Student_id": "102", "Name": "Snow", "Course" : "Medical" }, { "Student_id": "103", "Name": "Walter", "Course" : "Chemistry" }, { "Student_id": "104", "Name": "White", "Course" : "Chemistry" } ] } );

SELECT (OBJECT v.Course||"Students":v.cnt
       FOR v IN ARRAY_APPEND(ds, {"Course":"", "cnt": ARRAY_SUM(ds[*].cnt)})
       END).*
LET ds = (SELECT s.Course|| " " AS Course , COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM default AS d
           UNNEST d.Students AS s
           GROUP BY s.Course);
```